# PHP File uploading - accents and spaces in file names

Tags: php, file-upload, filenames

Is it necessary, in a context of file uploading (PHP website), in a Unix environment, to remove spaces and accents in file names ?
The only goal is to allow users to upload files and other users to download those files.
In that scenario, can spaces and accents cause any trouble ?

Answer (score 2):

> **Can spaces and accents cause any trouble?**

They can, not because the OS can't support them, but because PHP fails miserably dealing with even the most basic diactrics (you would have to `utf8_[en/de]code` even the basic ISO-8859-1 charset).

And forget about other, more complicated charsets.

Answer (score 0):

if you properly escape the special characters on retrieval (e.g. add an `\` before it), spaces and accents shouldn't be a problem

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "special characters" ?

Comment: special characters is probably the wrong word. I meant the accents and space charater. And remember to URL-escape the charaters if you want to use the filename in an URL (e.g. `%20` for space).

Comment: I've never seen anyone escaping accented characters, this seems strange to me. As far as using the filename in a URL, it works without URL encoding the filename so I was wondering if it was useful...